# R Shiny: sidebar not displaying correctly when using lapply()

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying to create a sidebar using lapply().

The following works as I want it:

```
header  = dashboardHeader(title = "Performance Dashboard", titleWidth = 320)
weekSelectSidebar  = sliderInput(inputId = "week", label = "Select Week in Semster:", min = 1, max = 3, value = 1, step = 1)
taskeSelectSidebar = menuItem("Enter Completed Tasks", tabName = "tasks", icon = icon("th"),

                        conditionalPanel(condition =" input.week == '1' ", menuSubItem(text = "Week 1", tabName = "W1")),

                        conditionalPanel(condition =" input.week == '2' ", menuSubItem(text = "Week 1", tabName = "W1"),
                                                                           menuSubItem(text = "Week 2", tabName = "W2")),

                        conditionalPanel(condition =" input.week == '3' ", menuSubItem(text = "Week 1", tabName = "W1"),
                                                                           menuSubItem(text = "Week 2", tabName = "W2"),
                                                                           menuSubItem(text = "Week 3", tabName = "W3")))


sidebar = dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(id = "sidebarMenu", weekSelectSidebar, taskSelectSidebar, width = 320))

body = dashboardBody()
ui   = dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)
server = function(input, output) {}
```

I have 12 weeks to go through so I wanted to use lapply(). I have tried the following:

```
header  = dashboardHeader(title = "Performance Dashboard", titleWidth = 320)
weekSelectSidebar  = sliderInput(inputId = "week", label = "Select Week in Semster:", min = 1, max = 3, value = 1, step = 1)
sidebar = dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(id = "sidebarMenu", weekSelectSidebar, sidebarMenuOutput("TaskSelect"), width = 320))

body = dashboardBody()

ui   = dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

server = function(input, output) {



output$TaskSelect = renderMenu({

w = input$week

menuItem("Enter Completed Tasks:",
         icon = icon("th"),
         lapply(1:w, function(i) {
           menuSubItem(text = paste0("Week ", i), tabName = paste0("W", i))
         })

         )




})
```

This doesn't seem to work.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues with your code. First: to include a `menuItem()` dynamically, use `menuItemOutput()`, not `sidebarMenuOutput()`. The more tricky one however is the second issue.

You want to pass a list (the result of `lapply()`) to the `...` argument of `menuItem()`. This should be done with `do.call()` to expand the list into several arguments. Otherwise, you basically have a call of the following form

```r
## not rendered correctly
menuItem(
  name = "Enter Completed Tasks:",
  list(
    sub_items[[1]],
    sub_items[[2]]
  ) 
)
```

which will not render correctly in a shiny application. This is because `menuItem` expects all arguments (except `name` and some other special arguments) to be of "type" subItem, not of type list.

```r
## rendered correctly
menuItem(
  name = "Enter Completed Tasks:",
  sub_items[[1]],
  sub_items[[2]]
)
```

`do.call()` can be used to get around this complication: the following chunk creates the same ui tag as the last chunk.

```
## rendered correctly
do.call(
  munuItem,
  list(name = "Enter Completed Tasks:", sub_items[[1]], sub_items[[2]])
)
```

A reproducible solution based on your testcase:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

weekSelectSidebar  = sliderInput(
  inputId = "week", 
  label = "Select Week in Semster:", 
  min = 1, max = 3, value = 1, step = 1)
sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    id = "sidebarMenu", 
    weekSelectSidebar, 
    menuItemOutput("TaskSelect"),              ## use the appropriate output function
    width = 320
  )
)

ui   = dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(), sidebar, dashboardBody())

server = function(input, output) {
  output$TaskSelect = renderMenu({
    w = input$week
    sub_items <- lapply(1:w, function(i) {
      menuSubItem(text = paste0("Week ", i), 
      tabName = paste0("W", i))
    })
    do.call(                                   ## use do.call() to pass a list to ...
      menuItem,
      args = c(name = "Enter Completed Tasks:", sub_items)
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

#### Alternative approach

Instead of using `do.call()`, it is also possible to change the type of `sub_items` to `tag.list`. See `?shiny::tagList` for the documentation.

```
server = function(input, output) {
  output$TaskSelect = renderMenu({
    w = input$week
    sub_items <- lapply(1:w, function(i) {
      menuSubItem(text = paste0("Week ", i), tabName = paste0("W", i))
    })
    class(sub_items) <- c("list", "tag.list")
    menuItem(text = "Enter Completed Tasks:", sub_items)
  })
}
```

I personally would suggest the solution that makes use of `do.call()` since it is more in line with the argument documentation of `menuItem()`. Also, explicitly setting class attributes is generally not a good habit unless you are the a collaborator on the class code.